# Access specific element of an array using Lodash in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have this array of object

```
const database = {
    users: [
    {
        id:1,
        name: "John",
        email: "john@gmail.com",
        passowrd: "h4ckM3!ifuc4n",
        entries: 0,
        joined: new Date(),

    },
    {
        id:2,
        name: "Mila",
        email: "mila@gmail.com",
        passowrd: "mila",
        entries: 0,
        joined: new Date(),

    },
    {
        id:3,
        name: "Luke",
        email: "luke@gmail.com",
        passowrd: "123",
        entries: 0,
        joined: new Date(),

    }

    ]
}
```

I'm trying to query a specific element from that array

```
app.get("/profile/:id", function (req, res) {

    console.log(req.params.id);
    // const user = _.find(database.users, {id: req.params.id });

    var user = _.find(database.users, {id:req.params.id});
    console.log(user);

    if(!user) {
       res.status(404).json("no user found");
    }

});
```

---

I kept getting

```
Example app listening on port 3002!
1
undefined
```

Any hints for me?

Comment: `req.params.id` will be string...convert to number

Comment: Why bother with Lodash? `const user = database.users.find(({ id }) => id == req.params.id)`. The `==` comparison will compare numbers with numeric strings without requiring parsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You really do not need lodash for that. I would not suggest using it since it creates unnecessary overhead.

```js
const user = database.users.find(user => user.id == req.params.id)
```

Should work just fine.

be aware that `==` is an unsafe check, and in case `req.params.id` is `undefined` it would match a user with the `id` of 0.

to mitigate this you could convert the `req.params.id` to a number and use a safe check operator `===` instead. (it checks that they aren't just comparable, but actually the same type and value)

```js
const user = database.users.find(user => user.id === parseInt(req.params.id, 10)
```

Comment: Thanks, Jonas, it's a clean and simple JS solution.